# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows when trying to insert from another select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert values into a field from another table.

This is what my code looks like,

```
declare @inventory_Num nvarchar(50);
set @inventory_Num=(select inventory_Num from tblOrders);
insert into tblInventoryDetails(inventoy_Num,Date)
select @inventory_Num,getDate()
```

I know my sub query returns 1000's of rows but i need to load all the inventory_num from orders.

Comment: `sql` is not enough! Please state your DBMS (vendor and version)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+subquery+returned+more+than+1+value

Comment: Insert .. select will load all rows http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp But are you sure , if you repeat this query it will load the data again. Shouldn't there be some checks to prevent doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this Works

```
insert into tblInventoryDetails(inventoy_Num,Date)
select inventory_Num,getDate() 'Date' from tblOrders
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you find it usefull @user6756721

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by doing

```
INSERT INTO tblInventoryDetails(inventoy_Num,Date)
SELECT inventory_Num,GETDATE() 
FROM tblOrders
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use query like this

```
insert into tblInventoryDetails (inventoy_Num, Date) 
select inventory_Num, getdate()  
from tblOrders
```

Comment: i need to load the above fetched data into .csv file format and to store in some folder path. How can i achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @LT268 -you can use this query for the same insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.csv;', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]') select * from SQLServerTable